# Moving to preprocessor to avoid indirection

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have an array of structure:

```
typedef struct s_values{
   field1; 
   field2;
   field3;
}t_values;

t_values values[5];
```

So, there are 5 types and each types has three fields.
To get the value for a particular type and field is got using `values[type].field`

I want to move away from this structure and instead use constant macros.

The goal is to have a macro
`#define VALUE(type, field)` 
 :- where type is an enum and field is just the field name

How do I go about doing that?

I was thinking something like:

```
#define VALUE2(type, field)  type##field
#define VALUE(type, field)   VALUE2(type, field)

#define type1field1   7
#define type2field2   67
....
```

But type is actually an enum..
Also, I am not sure if using ## beats the purpose of avoiding indirection..

Anyone has a better idea.. or help to improve the direction in which I was going?

Comment: *"I want to move away from this structure and instead use constant macros."* Why? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Need the values to be compile time constants for improving performance. 
And also have the code such that I can go back to previous model by just changing one macro #define(type, field)   values[type].field

Comment: Did you profile your code to identify performance problems?

Answer (score 1):

If `type` is a constant value anytime you use the construct `values[type].field` (the only case where you can hope to replace that construct with a “constant macro”), then the compiler will access it directly. In addition, if you marked the array `values` as `const`, it will know to replace `values[type].field` by the value of the member `field` of `values[type]`, as if you had written a constant expression. Any reasonable optimizing compiler will do this for free, you don't need to pollute the source code for this. Any reasonable C compiler should hard-code the value 67 in the code of `f` [here, as GCC does](https://godbolt.org/g/AqehiW):

```
typedef struct s_values{
   int field1; 
   int field2;
   int field3;
}t_values;

const t_values values[5] = {7, 67};

int f(void) {
  return values[0].field2;
}
```

---

If `type` is not a constant value when you use `values[type].field` then it cannot be replaced by a “constant macro”. The mapping from `type` and `field` has to be stored somewhere, and it takes an indirection to access it where it is stored. What the compiler will do for free in this case is to add the offset corresponding to `field` to the address where the array `value` is stored, so that the address to access is computed with only one multiplication and one addition (instead of two) at run-time. Again, this is optimal.